# FromClause.select() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: select, import, sqlalchemy

The select method must be prefixed with with alchemy.

```py
import sqlalchemy as alchemy
from sqlalchemy import select, text, column, values

s = alchemy.select(cookies.c.cookie_name,
                       cookies.c.quantity)
```

'select' was already imported from sqlalchemy, but it was necessary to add an import statement for sqlalchemy and qualify the 'select' with the import name 'alchemy.'
Without the qualified select, (alchemy.select(...), there is an error "two many arguments for the select method"

The question is why?

```py
import sqlalchemy as alchemy
from sqlalchemy import select, text, column, values

def queries_selected_columns(connection, metadata):
    """
    Select only a couple of columns to retrieve from the cookies table.
    """

    # Retrieve the cookies table object from the metadata
    cookies = metadata.tables["cookies"]

    # Build the SQL statement
    # s = cookies.select(cookies.c.cookie_name, cookies.c.quantity)
    s = alchemy.select(cookies.c.cookie_name,
                       cookies.c.quantity)
    rp = connection.execute(s)  # Create the result proxy
    print("\nFetch the cookie name and quantity")
    print(rp.keys())
    result = rp.first()
    print(f"result: {result}")
```

The error when just 'select(...)' is used and not 'alchemy.select(...)'

```
TypeError: FromClause.select() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given


 (venv) E:\www\sandbox\alchemy\playground>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\www\sandbox\alchemy\playground\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    queries_selected_columns(connection, metadata)
  File "E:\www\sandbox\alchemy\playground\db_querries.py", line 111, in queries_selected_columns
    s = cookies.select(cookies.c.cookie_name, cookies.c.quantity)
TypeError: FromClause.select() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given      

(venv) E:\www\sandbox\alchemy\playground>
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand the question you seem to be mixing https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select and https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select. `cookies.select` is *not* the same as `alchemy.select` edit: @snakecharmerb has left a better explaining suggestion

Answer (score 2):

When you call `cookies.select` you are calling the table object's [select method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select).  This method is more limited than [sqlalchemy.select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) - it just selects all the columns in the table. Consequently it doesn't take any arguments when called.

Use the table's `select` method only if you want to select all the columns in a table. If you want to select only some of the columns, or add extra columns, use `sqlalchemy.select`. Or just use `sqlalchemy.select` everywhere, as it provides a superset of the functionality of `Table.select`.

Comment: "sqlalchemy.select. Or just use sqlalchemy.select." did you mean for them both to be the same?

Comment: Yes!  The OP could use `Table.select` for `select *` type queries, and `sqlalchemy.select` for more complex queries, but in practice I find it's simpler just to use `sqlalchemy.select` in all cases.